# Action faster than method call?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

Some time ago I did found an article about Action's being faster than pure method calls. I cannot remember where, but in the moment was shoked, did some tests and found it where true in some cases.

Today someone just said what I was testing was wrong, so, can someone find a cause to in these tests Action's without parameters are faster than pure methods? I must say it's only faster in x64 machines, in x86 are slower.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        test t = new test();
        t.doTest();
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}

class test
{
    Stopwatch w;
    int a = 0;

    public void doTest()
    {
        Action doSum = () => { a = a + 1; };
        Action<int> doSumValue = (add) => { a = a + add; };

        w = new Stopwatch();

       Console.WriteLine("-------With params-------");
        for (int round = 0; round < 10; round++)
        {

            a = 0;
            w.Reset();
            w.Start();

            for (int buc = 0; buc < 500000000; buc++)
                sumValue(1);

            w.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Function: " + w.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            a = 0;
            w.Reset();
            w.Start();

            for (int buc = 0; buc < 500000000; buc++)
                doSumValue(1);

            w.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Action: " + w.ElapsedMilliseconds);



        }

       Console.WriteLine("-------With no params---------");
        for (int round = 0; round < 10; round++)
        {

            a = 0;
            w.Reset();
            w.Start();

            for (int buc = 0; buc < 500000000; buc++)
                sum();

            w.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Function: " + w.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            a = 0;
            w.Reset();
            w.Start();

            for (int buc = 0; buc < 500000000; buc++)
                doSum();

            w.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Action: " + w.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        }
    }

    void sum()
    {
        a = a + 1;
    }

    void sumValue(int toAdd)
    {
        a = a + toAdd;
    }

}
```

**EDIT: Changed loop count to surpase 1 sec with same results**

The results on my machine (i7 2600) are these:

**NEW RESULTS WITH A LOT OF ITERATIONS**

-x86
*With params

Function: 1417ms
Action: 1568ms

*Without params

Function: 1422ms
Action: 1634ms

-x64
*With params

Function: 1976ms
Action: 2114ms

*Without params

Function: 1975ms
Action: 1719ms

**OLD RESULTS WITH LOW ITERATION COUNT**

**-x86 With params**

Function: 28ms

Action: 31ms

**-x86 Without params**

Function: 28ms

Action: 32ms

**-x64 With params**

Function: 39ms

Action: 42ms

**-x64 With params**

**Function: 39ms**

**Action: 34ms**

So, is my test wrong or actions are faster than calls to parameterless methods in x64 machines?

Comment: I wouldn't trust any timings that small to start with, to be honest. When there's only a few milliseconds in it, that can easily be for reasons which have nothing to do with the code you're running. I would increase the number of iterations so that you were timing for *at least* a second, and ideally rather longer.

Comment: (I'd also suggest that you edit your post to make the code easier to read - there's no reason for quite so many blank lines all the way through.)

Comment: Benchmarking is hard. Harder than you think.

Comment: Because that I put it in a loop, to let it stabilze, but well, I will try with more iterations and post results

Comment: I'd say do timings _much_ longer than a second. There are so many possible things potentially contributing to those timings that you cannot say with any certainty which one is faster.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, because of that I want to know where the test is wrong (if it is).

Comment: Beware of micro-benchmarks: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: You should also do a "dry-run" to account for JIT compilation on first call.

Comment: First of all, document your results better: Debug/Release, IDE attached? And use some code less likeley to be optimized away.

Answer (score 1):

`Action` is a delegate.  This, for all intents and purposes in .NET, is just a method pointer.  i.e. it's just a pointer to a method, so logically it performs the same basic instructions and calls a method under the covers.  There's no *general* reason why Action would be faster than a direct call to the same method wrapped by Action.  There's many scenarios where it might be slightly slower because it's a level of abstraction around a method call--but not in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

Well,  Henk Holterman had the key, I was running it in release mode but launching it from visual studio.

Launching it manually they behave at same speed, not action being faster (and with params being a lot slower).

Would love to find again that article here I did found this info to send him those results.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: If you find the article, please post--I'd very much like to avoid that publication.